# Bind each keyboard layout to keys combination

Tags: keyboard

There is a nice possibility to bind each keyboard layout to separate keys combination and switch between them.

So you can assign, for instance, shortcut Alt-Shift-0 to "Select English", Alt-Shift-1 to "Select German", Alt-Shift-2 to "Select Arabic".

How to make this on MacOS 10.7.4?

Comment: Keyboard layout? You mean Dvorak, qwerty, arabic and stuff?

Comment: mm.. I mean U.S. English, Dvokar English, German, Arabic, etc.

Comment: And I mean to switch between layouts

Comment: @kim what do you mean by "add to sidebar" and can you explain the part with the 1st menu item etc.... Trying to set this up with Hebrew/English/Russian/Spanish all at once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hurray! I found a way:

1. Add layouts in side bar
2. create an applescript

like this:

```
on changeKeyboardLayout(layoutName)
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    tell (1st menu bar item of menu bar 1 whose description is "text input") to {click, click (menu 1's menu item layoutName)}
end tell
end changeKeyboardLayout

changeKeyboardLayout("US Extended")
```

3.Save it in /Library/Scripts

4.Bind it to the keys combination [using FastScript](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2007/06/08/hit-and-run-launching-applescripts-with-keyboard-shortcuts.html?page=3)

Comment: Ok, this is ancient history by now, but just in case someone else is wondering: this no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way -  use free utility [Kawa](https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa)

It solves topickstarter request exactly (*"to bind each keyboard layout to separate keys combination and switch between them."*)

```
brew install --cask kawa
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add details on how kawa can be used to solve the problem described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to System Preferences > Language and Text > Input Sources.
2. Select whatever layouts you want in the sidebar.
3. You can switch between the layouts using the shortcut using command + [ or command + ].
4. If you want to change the shortcut, go to the Keyboard preference pane > Keyboard Shortcuts > Keyboard and Text Input.
5. Here you can change the shortcuts for “Select the next input source” and “Select the previous input source”.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question. My question not about shortcuts "Select next" and "Select previous". I'm asking how to create shortcuts "Select English", "Select German", "Select Arabic".

Comment: Not possible. Nope.

Comment: You are wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I have improved this script

you could find your answer below

[how to specify the keyboard layout or called input source with shortcut/](https://blog.do.church/how-to-specify-the-keyboard-layout-or-called-input-source-with-shortcut/)

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: hope that helps:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180813201822/https://blog.do.church/how-to-specify-the-keyboard-layout-or-called-input-source-with-shortcut/

btw: in that article the main point is about this github project: https://github.com/minoki/InputSourceSelector