# Assign a key combination for each input language

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I know I can "cycle through languages" and "toggle between last used two languages" with key combinations. These options are not so convenient when you have three or more input languages installed.

Is there any way to assign a key combination for each language, not cycling or toggling? For the sake of example, if I can press Command + 1 then the input mode is changed to English, if Command + 2 then Japanese, if Command + 3 then Korean. Something like that.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61250/bind-each-keyboard-layout-to-keys-combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First enable all necessary layouts in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter customized input source definitions and keycodes

   Example:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>

     <vkchangeinputsourcedef>
       <name>KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_US</name>
       <inputsourceid_equal>com.apple.keylayout.US</inputsourceid_equal>
     </vkchangeinputsourcedef>

     <item>
       <name>Change input source to US by right shift key + U</name>
       <identifier>private.change_input_source_to_us</identifier>
       <autogen>
         __KeyToKey__
         KeyCode::U, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R,
         KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_US
       </autogen>
     </item>

     <vkchangeinputsourcedef>
       <name>KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_GERMAN</name>
       <languagecode>de</languagecode>
     </vkchangeinputsourcedef>

     <item>
       <name>Change input source to German by right shift key + D</name>
       <identifier>private.change_input_source_to_german</identifier>
       <autogen>
         __KeyToKey__
         KeyCode::D, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R,
         KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_GERMAN
       </autogen>
     </item>

     <vkchangeinputsourcedef>
       <name>KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_UNICODEHEXINPUT</name>
       <inputsourceid_equal>com.apple.keylayout.UnicodeHexInput</inputsourceid_equal>
     </vkchangeinputsourcedef>

       <item>
       <name>Change input source to HEX by right shift key + H</name>
       <identifier>private.change_input_source_to_hex</identifier>
       <autogen>
         __KeyToKey__
         KeyCode::H, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R,
         KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_UNICODEHEXINPUT
       </autogen>
       </item>

   </root>
   ```

   In the example hitting <kbd>right shift</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> will enable the US layout, <kbd>right shift</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> the german layout and <kbd>right shift</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> the hex layout.

   A comprehensive list of *vkchangeinputsourcedefs* is available [here](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/blob/version_10.14.0/src/core/server/Resources/vkchangeinputsourcedef.xml).
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable all "shortcuts". They are listed at the beginning.

Comment: I tried and it seems to work. I just have one more question. I do not use Apple's Japanese input but Google Japanese Input (a third-party IME https://tools.google.com/dlpage/japaneseinput/eula.html?platform=mac&hl=ja). How can I get the "identifier" and "inputsourceid_equal" and "languagecode" for Google Japanese IME?

Comment: @SinJeong-hun Good question. I have to examine this first.

Comment: @SinJeong-hun The *item identifier* as well as the *item name* and probably the *vkchangeinputsourcedef KEYCODE name* (e.g. VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_UNICODEHEXINPUT) and the corresponding *item KEYCODE* (e.g. VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_UNICODEHEXINPUT) are user defined and have to be unique. So only the *inputsourceid_equal* and maybe the *language code* are missing

Comment: My mistake. I typed "jp" for "languagecode", but it should be "ja". Now, switching to Google Japanese IME works. The only problem is that sometimes (I have not yet found out the exact condition) the IME seems to be switched (flag and check mark changed in the status bar) to Korean but still English is typed.

Comment: @SinJeong-hun You may try [other](https://gist.github.com/keekun/f69ea0a5f568e1668394) settings in private.xml

Comment: I asked about that (icon changed, but not the actual mode) to the Karabiner's forum and got a reply. Basically, it is a known issue of OS X with Asian languages and I should use Command + Option + Space (switching to the next input) instead.

Comment: And it doesn't work for Sierra.

Comment: @St.Shadow Karabiner has to be recoded & updated for Sierra first. The answer isn't intended to work with Karabiner Elements.