# How to change keyboard layout to specific language with hotkey in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard

How can I change my keyboard layout to English with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and change layout to Russian with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>?

An old version of Punto Switcher could do this on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

For the general case of changing input sources via keyboard shortcuts, see [this earlier question.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61250/bind-each-keyboard-layout-to-keys-combination)

Another approach might be to use the app [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to design a custom keyboard that does what you want, but it would be a lot of work.

If it would be enough to use Caps Lock to switch between English and Russian, you can do this by just checking a box at the bottom of System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late but another option is to use [Karabiner-Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) which is really flexible and well-documented. Add the following settings to a profile in karabiner.json following [the reference](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html).

```
{
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "description": "capslock -> toggle russian",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "caps_lock",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [],
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "select_input_source": {
                        "language": "ru"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```