# Can I make Caps Lock always switch to a specific input language?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, language

My 12" MacBook has the Chinese (Simplified, Pinyin) hardware keyboard and it has the default function on <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> that lets you switch the language input between Chinese and English.

However, I also use Japanese, Korean and Russian keyboards and found out that the capslock doesn't let you switch between Chinese and English. It just switches to the last used keyboard. So for example, if you type in English, switch to Korean, switch to English, and tap on the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, you get the Korean keyboard, not Chinese.

I always want Chinese keyboard on whenever I tap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. Is it possible on macOS?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Why is it a duplicate?

Comment: It's not possible.  For making shortcuts to invoke specific keyboards, see for example https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61250/bind-each-keyboard-layout-to-keys-combination

Comment: @TomGewecke the article you cite goes on to explain how to make it happen. You get some keyboard remapper and assign an applescript to caps lock.

Comment: @historystamp  Good point, you could indeed use it for that, at least in theory.  Maybe that is the fix.