# Shortcut to switch to a given input source

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, input-source

Is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut for each individual input source, so that I can pick whichever input source I want, simply using the keyboard, without having to scroll through a whole list of them? Note that I use the application Ukelele to make custom keyboards, if that has any bearing on potential answers.

Running 11.6.4 on a 2020 Macbook Air.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61250/bind-each-keyboard-layout-to-keys-combination/434554#434554

Answer (score 3):

The Kawa app can do what you are asking.

https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa

Comment: Oh my goodness this is almost exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This addresses only this part: "I can pick whichever input source I want, simply using the keyboard". Prerequisite: "whichever inputs" must be added prior Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources

There is built-in keyboard shortcut for switching to previous input source: <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>␣</kbd> (control+space). While pressing them briefly it will select previous input source (good if switching between two sources), pressing and holding these keys will bring up input source changing pop-up window. While keeping <kbd>⌃</kbd> pressed it is possible select desired input source using the space bar <kbd>␣</kbd>.

Keyboard shortcut is defined and can be changed under Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Input Sources > Select the previous input source

Comment: @TomGewecke - I wanted to say that  every spacebar/space key press will move selection to next input source in pop-up window. Works on ABC which should be same as US